# how to change color of navbar in laravel?

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am unable to change color of my "navbar-default" that is defined in bootstrap.css file under my public folder. I am using bootstrap 3.3.5 files. Changes do not appear when I reload the page. Help me out please as its first time I am sing custom styling in a Laravel project.
[image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we0WG.png)

Comment: Override the bootstrap class on your own css file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your custom class and style it such as 
`.my-navebar-style`

or add `background-color: red !important;` at the end for your property.

And make sure your CSS file should be include towards after bootstrap.css

Comment: Using `!important` is never a good idea, but if you're going to do it, you need to prefix it with `!` for it to work.

Comment: Yes Kirk, I've just forgot to add exclamation mark anyways thanks